# Why do I need to update if nobody has committed?

Tags: linux, svn, version-control

I've recently started using Subversion on the command line. I committed a couple of times, and fiddled with the ignore lists and such.

Today I came to commit more changes. And SVN *demanded* that I perform an update before committing.

This was strange, because nobody else had committed. I know this for a fact. And therefore I didn't want to update, because by definition, if my working copy is "correct", then any changes would make it "incorrect".

As I understand it, "updating" is the process of merging *other people's committed changes* - ones that happened *since you last updated or checked out* - with your local working copy.

**So my question is, if nobody touched the repository since I last committed, why couldn't I commit again without first updating?**

My colleague suggested that maybe I had deleted a file or directory without telling SVN. But again: those were *my* changes, and they occurred *after* the last commit. Surely any changes to my working copy should *supersede* any and all prior commits?

**As a follow-up question:** How can I determine which files have changed on the server since I last updated, without *actually* updating? I tried `svn diff` and it listed a bunch of changes that I had performed at my end. Which isn't really very helpful.

When I ran `svn up` it just said:

```
Updating '.':
At revision 4.
```

Thus proving, to my mind, that the update was unnecessary.

Comment: use `svn status` to see what has changed.

Comment: why would the server recognize your working copy as "correct"? Isn't the point of centralized version control to have the server act as the source of truth?

Comment: @Z4-tier Of course. But the server was, unfortunately, lying. And that's my concern.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you. That's the follow-up question taken care of, at least.

Comment: My guess is something in your repo got modified so it's out of sync with the server, and updating gets them back in sync.

Comment: But it's only changes *to the server copy* that should require an update, right? Local changes to my working copy should only require a commit.

Comment: How did it make these demands? Could it be a "convenience" feature to ensure that especially old changes aren't automerged?

Comment: Might have been a property change.

Comment: @thatotherguy Can't be especially old. Was like, two days ago. It made these demands by saying `E170004: commit failed - item '/code' is out of date` (which it wasn't). And a "convenience feature" would conveniently have a `--force` override option.

Comment: @stark A property change on the server, you mean? Because a property change in my working copy should not require an update.

Comment: Two days is way too old to push, but in any case, can you make sure to [copy-paste the error exactly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough)? Are you able to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Two days is when I did more work on the project. No point in committing when I've not done anything. A screenshot of the exact error message can be seen here: http://snpy.in/8S4vlY

Comment: The issue has not happened again since. But as it's only been an hour or so, that's not surprising.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer your follow-up question on how to check which files were changed on server:

```
svn status --show-updates
```

or in a short form:

```
svn st -u
```

As for main question, I bet you are dealing with either mixed-revisions working copy or properties update (or smth). It would be helpfull if you be able to reproduce the scenario and provide the details.

Comment: Whatever the property changes or "smth", they would all have happened LOCALLY. So my question boils down to: why should local changes cause an update to be mandated?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "mixed revisions working copy", but there are no forks and I only created the repo a few days ago.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem because I don't know what caused it.